# Execute terminal command without forking

Tags: c++, c, linux, terminal, fork

Is there a possibility to execute a shell command and read its output result without calling `popen()` (or `system()`). The goal is to avoid forking the program.

EDIT: I'd prefer to have a multithreaded solution instead of a multiprocess solution.

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear, please elaborate

Comment: by "read its string" do you actually mean "read its output" ?

Comment: `popen()` and `system()` will both create a fork under the hood.

Comment: you can run a program by means of `exec()` but doing so will overlay the calling process. May I ask why you want to avoid forking?

Comment: Is there no way to run a shell command multithreaded?

Comment: @Levi _"Is there no way to run a shell command multithreaded?"_ No, it needs a separate process of course.

Comment: If you want to avoid forking in the process, then use an another process to do that. You don't need to start the another process by your process.